# Creating a regression model that will predict price of a product

Tags: numpy, machine-learning, scikit-learn, linear-regression, data-science

I have data for companies selling certain quantities of the same products at certain prices please refer below:

```
Company A:
(qty)     (price)
100        1000
200        1800
300        2400

Company B:
(qty)     (price)
110       1000
200       1770
300       2390

Company C:
(qty)     (price)
1000       10000
1500       13000
3700       22000
```

I want to create a model that will roughly predict the price of a certain quantity of the product based on the data. I am using sickitlearn and I have tried collecting all quantities in one array and price in another. for example:
all quantities from all 3 companies in a numpy array:

```
import numpy as np
train_qty = np.array([[100,200,300,110,200,300,1000,1500,3700]])
```

for prices:

```
train_prices = np.array([[1000,1800,300,110,200,300,1000,1500,3700]])
```

I tried:

```
from sklearn import linear_model 
reg = linear.model.LinearRegression()
reg.fit(train_qty,train_prices)
```

However, when I do:

```
print(reg.coef_)
```

I get a matrix of all zeros. Could you explain what I did wrong and the right way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be

```
reg.fit(train_qty.T, train_prices.T)
reg.coef_  # 0.85178458
```

The sklearn linear model looks for the coefs `A` so that `XA = Y`. Here your `train_qty` and `train_prices` are both matrix 1 x 9, so you obtain `A` a matrix 9 x 9. You have to transpose your input.

Answer (score 0):

Another option to get one dimensional arrays is to use reshape:

```
train_qty = np.array([[100,200,300,110,200,300,1000,1500,3700]]).reshape(-1,1)
train_prices = np.array([[1000,1800,300,110,200,300,1000,1500,3700]]).reshape(-1,1)
```